# [__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e09f70'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Getting the error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e09f70'

```
if (finalArray.count != 0)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *fetchDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSMutableArray *valueArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[fetchDict allValues].mutableCopy];


        for (NSMutableArray *one in valueArr) {
            for (NSMutableArray *two in one) // Program Stops on This Line
            {
                cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[two valueForKey:@"Note"]];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so you think the array contains arrays, but it doesn't, it contains at least one string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
if (finalArray.count != 0)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *fetchDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSMutableArray *valueArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[fetchDict allValues].mutableCopy];


    for (NSMutableArray *one in valueArr) {
        if ([one isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) { //Check if array here
            for (NSMutableArray *two in one) 
            {
                cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[two valueForKey:@"Note"]];
            }
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Program stops because this one: %@", one);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Worked Thanks !! Cheers !! (y)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (finalArray.count != 0)
    {
        NSDictinory *fetchDict = [finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fetchDict valueForKey:@"Note"]];

    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh for your efforts. Tim007 gave the working solution.